# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I really can't get my navigation to work.I am using react-navigation (StackNavigator).

This is my structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8SJ1.png

My navigation works in `HomeScreen.js`: I navigate from `HomeScreen.js` to `NewScreen.js` without problems.

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StatusBar, AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {HomeScreen} from './screens/HomeScreen';
import AboutScreen from "./screens/AboutScreen";
import NewScreen from "./screens/NewScreen";
import CalendarScreen from "./screens/CalendarScreen";
import AddAgendaScreen from "./screens/AddAgendaScreen";

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    About: {screen: AboutScreen},
    New: {screen: NewScreen},
    Calendar: {screen: CalendarScreen},
    AddAgenda: {screen: AddAgendaScreen}
});

console.disableYellowBox = true;
StatusBar.setHidden(true);
export default SimpleApp; // Export root navigator as the root component
```

**Homescreen.js (working):**

```
export class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const {state, navigate} = navigation;
    return {
      title: 'eXopera'
    };
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      address: [],
      refreshing: false,
      page: 1,
      lastPage: 1,
      loading: true,
      listOpacity: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {   
    return (
      <ScrollableTabView style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}} renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar  />}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}} tabLabel="Adressen">
          <Button color="#33cd5f" title="NEW"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('New') }/>
        </View>
      </ScrollableTabView>
    );
  }
}
```

Then there is another component called CalendarScreen.js (where I also try to navigate to NewScreen.js), even if I completely copy and paste the code from HomeScreen.js, I am unable to navigate. It always gives me "**undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')**".

I really don't know what I can do now.. Have been struggling with this for hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to remove `console.disableYellowBox` to see if you get any early warnings. Also at what point exactly do you get the error. Is it when you click on the button from the NewScreen?

Comment: It's when I click the button from the NewScreen indeed. I have removed `console.disableYellowBox` without success: no warnings.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted as far as I can tell. Could you post NewScreen.js too?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dev/b4f031980c1fd7862b23b0edfdc62963

Comment: Hard to tell. Try to put `console.info(this.props); console.info(this.props.navigation);` on top of the NewScreen `render()` method to try to narrow it down a bit. If you don't have any navigation object at this point, then the problem is somewhere before that. Also there's a circular reference between App and the screens, and RN doesn't handle that well, so maybe something to look at too.

Comment: console.info(this.props); console.info(this.props.navigation); gives undefined! :(

Comment: Have you tried this with the new `createStackNavigator()` function instead of the (now depreceated i think) `StackNavigator`? I'm seeing the same error and trying to figure out what it means

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apart from react-navigation, I was also using [react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view).

I have solved it by passing the navigation props through the tab navigation:

`<CalendarScreen navigation={this.props.navigation} tabLabel="Agenda"/>`

Then you can access it in the other components as `this.props.navigation` as well.

Comment: This is what the correct path to navigate between screen. if you use components on a view. we should pass the props as it mentioned and then we can push the navigation router from our component. Thank You @KennyHietbrink

Comment: This is Correct Solution for **react-native-scrollable-tab-view**

Answer (score 3):

I changed my method from `renderHeader(){ ... }` to

```
renderHeader = () => {
    const title= 'Sign Up';
    return (
      <View style={{
        padding: 20,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
      }}>
        <Icon
          onPress={() => {
                           this.props.navigation.navigate('find');
                         }
                  }
          name='arrow-back'
          type='MaterialIcons'
          color='white'
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

it solved this problem.

> use  renderHeader = () => {} instead of using renderHeader(){} is critically important in solving my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your new screen is not registered with the app navigator and so doesn't have the `navigation` props. Your constructor should be like this:

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  New: { screen: NewScreen }, // Add this
});
```

Comment: It is registered :[, updated OP with App.js file's code! Sorry, totally forgot to add the App.js code.

Answer (score 0):

Guys don't give bullsh*t answers, main thing is you need to give **permission** to access `props` to child component . slution =>  [Access the navigation prop from any component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/)